# Alternative to Bonferroni Correction for Dichotomous Variable?

Tags: nonparametric, bonferroni

I am working with a dichotomous variable and my supervisor has asked me to apply a Bonferroni correction to our data using SPSS. From my understanding, Bonferroni corrections are used when performing multiple comparisons, i.e., when we are testing more than one hypothesis. However, in our case, we only have two groups to compare for our dichotomous variable.

Could anyone suggest an alternative correction or procedure appropriate for this case? Or perhaps, am I misunderstanding the application of Bonferroni correction for my situation? Any insight or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your understanding of Bonferroni corrections matches mine.  I think either 

a) You misunderstood your supervisor
b) Your supervisor is wrong
c) You haven't fully explained what is going on.

b) is more likely if your supervisor is not a statistician.

However, if you only have one comparison, then there is no alternative to Bonferroni correction because there is nothing to correct. 

I suggest talking to your supervisor.

Comment: If you really do have multiple tests, you can exploit the discreteness of the response variables to get a much more powerful test than Bonferroni, while retaining familywise error control. See https://www.jstor.org/stable/2684683